# Changing attribute of subclass in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'd like to change the attributes for the subclass seen in the image below.

[image]

How do I select that specific object in the two different scenarios?

1) When creating the main class:

```
slider = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "slider")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + slider_translate_width + "," + 0 + ")")
        .attr("cursor", "default")
        .call(brush);
```

2) When using `svg.selectall("...")`

Comment: In both cases you call `.attr("width", ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the variable `slider` is the `<g class="slider">` element as pictured in the screenshot. Simply select the `rect` element by calling

```
var rect = slider.select('rect');
rect.attr('width', ...);

/* Or, chaining */
slider.select('rect').attr('width', ...);
```

You can also select the element using CSS selectors and `select` or `selectAll`:

```
d3.selectAll('.slider > rect').attr('width', ...);
```

Generally, the second method is **slower** because you're traversing the entire DOM as opposed to the first method, where you're only traversing the siblings of `<g class="slider">`.